# Facebook iOS In App Browser and 'Shared Web Credentials'

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, safari, keychain

Does anyone know if the Facebook In App Browser on iOS support '[Shared Web Credentials](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials)'

Basically, if I enable 'Shared Web Credentials' between by Website and my App, will the Facebook In App Browser also use these credentials to automatically log in?

I suspect this depends if the Facebook App uses SFSafariViewController or some other browser?

thanks
Adam